# Setup of multi-level and dependent observables

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I am trying to implement a solution for an angular application that returns the status of a multi-level procedure and processes the result or errors that have occurred. Instead of using a common object for the status and possible errors, I would like to use two separate channels for the successful and incorrect output.
The means of choice is the Observable.throw functionality ([link](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/throw.md)). The method should be called as follows:

```
myFunction(result).subscribe((status: boolean) => {
      console.log(data);          
    }, err => this.errorSub.next( err));
  }
```

If the procedure is completed correctly, the first method is called; if an error occurs, the second function with the error is called.

```
return this.service.createAndGetEntity(result.data.order)
  .map((response: EntityResponse<OrderModel>) => {

    if (result.data.unknownLocation) {
      if (result.data.isRedundant) {
        this.secondService.createWithRedundancy(someData).subscribe(() => {
          this.dispatchSuccessAction(newOrder);
          return true;
        }, (err) => {
          this.dispatchErrorAction(err);
          throw Observable.throw(err);
        });
      }
      else {
        this.secondService.createEntity(someData).subscribe(() => {
          this.dispatchSuccessAction(newOrder);
          return true;
        }, (err) => {
          this.dispatchErrorAction(err);
          throw Observable.throw(err);
        });
      }
    }
    else {
      this.dispatchSuccessAction(newOrder);
      // also return true here
    }
  });
```

Now to my problem: For the procedure to run correctly, interdependent subscriptions are required, which are executed one after the other based on the result of the previous step. The method should return an Observable at the end, but my snatz does not work. Therefore my question: How do I structure the different calls, so that at the end the correct order is run through and either a true is returned or an error is thrown with corresponding error text?

Comment: why are you throwing another error inside the error handler ( throw Observable.throw(err) ) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve the desired result the `mergeMap` operator.

```
import { mergeMap, map } from 'rxjs/operators';

createAndGetAntity(result) {
  return this.service.createAndGetEntity(result.data.order).pipe(
    mergeMap((response: EntityResponse<OrderModel>) => {
      if (result.data.unknownLocation) {
        if (result.data.isRedundant) {
          return this.secondService.createWithRedundancy(someData);
        } else {
          return this.secondService.createEntity(someData);
        }
      }
      return of(true);
    }),
    map(() => true),
  );
}
```

I would handle dispatching the success and error actions in the subscribe block, and not in the service method itself.

```
this.service.dispatchErrorAction(result).subscribe(
  (order) => this.dispatchSuccessAction(order), 
  (err) => this.dispatchErrorAction(err)
)
```

Comment: Looks great! just one question: How is is possible to map data and transfer them to the next step? The data should be mapped after createAndGetEntity and be passed to the next step. there is also data added.